# How to automatically export an Oracle Applications web form to PDF?

Tags: xml, oracle, forms, pdf, oracle-apex

The idea is, upon data entry, automatically export an Oracle Applications (web) form to PDF, storing it in the database.

Using XML Publisher, one can allow the user to export it on-demand, but I need to have the report/form PDF generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution is pretty much covered [here](http://apps2fusion.com/at/ps/51-ps/260-integrating-xml-publisher-and-oa-framework). Basically, with a bit of OAF code, one can have the form XML converted to PDF calling the XML Publisher API.

It would be interesting, though, to have the form XML generated automatically without needing a custom query + View Object.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be using [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/). After your form is saved, write a little class to generate the PDF file, and store it wherever you want.

It's not *automatic* for the programmer (you) since it involves writing a class for it, but it is *automatic* for the end user who won't have to do anything to get its form saved into a PDF file.